# Searching "aborted" files in directory

Tags: python, regex

My code searching `*.lis` files in directory and searching `aborted` - `*.lis` files.

Here is my code:

```
def aborted_files(file):
    in_file = open(file,'r')
    for lines in in_file.readlines():
        if re.search("aborted", lines):
            print in_file

    in_file.close()

for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".lis"):
        aborted_files(file)
```

I test it in 2 files `lisfile1.lis` and `lisfile2.lis`.

In `lisfile1.lis` I have `aborted` and the result of my code was:

```
<open file 'lisfile1.lis', mode 'r' at 0x2b0edd174660>
<open file 'lisfile1.lis', mode 'r' at 0x2b0edd174660>
```

Could you help me to get as result only `aborted` - `*.lis` file names.
What is incorrect in my code?

Comment: you want file names which has aborted in it?

Comment: You're results seem right. It prints out `listfile1.list` twice because you probably have `aborted` in the file twice and you're printing everytime you find the word.

Comment: No the reason wasn't it , mt loop work 2 times thats why i get filename twice.

Comment: And in each file i have just one aborted word

Thanks to everyone for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things here.

(1) You're printing the file for every match. I'm guessing if there are `>= 1` occurrences of `'aborted'`, you probably just want to print the filename once.
(2) You're printing out the actual file object, rather than the filename. Also you just be using `with open(...)`, which will handle closing the file for you.

```
def aborted_files(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as in_file:
        for lines in in_file.readlines():
            if re.search("aborted", lines):
                print in_file.name
                return
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to print the file name, you could just print out `file.name` variable.
2. And then, you don't need `re.search()` function here, just use `in`.
3. Use `return` to return the file name will be better than use `print`.

   However if you use print here, it will print a file name `n` times(`n` is how many `aborted` in that file).
4. `.readlines()` here is also useless.
5. use `with` to auto close the file will be more simpler and safer.

---

```
def aborted_files(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as in_file:
        for lines in in_file:
            if "aborted" in lines:
                return in_file.name

for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".lis"):
        print aborted_files(file)
```

Comment: OP asks specifically that he wants the results to be filenames